# How to connect HTML elements with a line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to *connect two div elements with a line* (also using a div). As you can see *below*, the line's length and rotation looks fine, but it's position highly varies from the expectation.
The green circle is the start node, it's position is *constant*, doesn't change, while the red one's position is *changable by clicking*. 
Using a canvas isn't an option since multiple lines will be generated and I need access to each of them (editing, deleting).

It'd be great if you could give it a look and give a solution hopefully or just a basic starting point. *Thanks in advance!*

[image: reference image]

Here's my code:

```js
var startNode = document.querySelector("#startnode");
var container = document.querySelector("#container");

container.addEventListener("click", SetNodePosition, false);

function SetNodePosition(e) {

  var startX = getElementPosition(startNode).x;
  var startY = getElementPosition(startNode).y;

  var nodeX = getElementPosition(node).x;
  var nodeY = getElementPosition(node).y;

  var mouseX = e.clientX - 25;
  var mouseY = e.clientY - 25;

  var newPosX = mouseX;//NEW NODE POSITION HAS TO BE CALCULATED
  var newPosY = mouseY;//THIS IS A PERMANENT SOLUTION

  console.log("Start: " + startX + " - " + startY);
  console.log("Node: " + nodeX + " - " + nodeY)
  console.log("Mouse: " + mouseX + " - " + mouseY)
  console.log("------------------")

  var translate3dValue = "translate3d(" + newPosX + "px," + newPosY + "px, 0)";
  node.style.transform = translate3dValue;

  if(typeof(document.getElementById("line1")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("line1") != null){
      updateLine(startX, nodeX, startY, nodeY, "line1");
  }
  else{
      createLine(startX, nodeX, startY, nodeY, "line1");
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
#startnode {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;

    transform: translate3d(200px, 25px, 0);
}
#node {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: move;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;

    transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, 0);
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="startnode"></div>
        <div id="node"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ps: my code has multiple bugs unrelated to the problem and i'm completely aware of it, i just want to get this part done first

Comment: Have you thought about using SVG instead of HTML elements?

Comment: Not really, why is it better? Sorry, I've just started frontend dev, so everything is new for me...

Comment: SVG is specifically for graphics—but it's still XML based, so you'd still have access to each element in the DOM. It has specific syntaxes for [lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line) and [circles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) which may make things much easier to work with.

Comment: Ooh sound good, thanks!